# Deal with Either as a fs.Stream

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats, fs2

If I have a `fs2.StreamApp[IO]`, how do I best deal with `Either` (or `\/`) when constructing the main app's stream?

For example, I build up some inputs to the program as an either (as I like the API -- it's telling me "something can go wrong" in the signature). If there is a problem, in this case with the command line arguments, I want a different stream returned from the main method.

```
private def extractArgs(args: List[String]): Error \/ List[_] = args match {
  case Nil  => CommandLineError().left
  case args => args.map(/* whatever */).right
}
```

When I get to the main method...

```
def stream(args: List[String], requestShutdown: IO[Unit]): Stream[IO, ExitCode] = {

  val application: Error \/ Stream[IO, ExitCode] = for {
    args   <- extractArgs(args)
    x      <- someOtherEither
  } yield Stream.eval(...)

  application match {
    case -\/(error) => Stream.eval(IO(Log.error(error.message))).flatMap(_ => Stream.emit(ExitCode(1)))
    case \/-(ok)    => ok
  }
}
```

...it all gets a bit ugly.

I could have the disjunction methods (`extractArgs`) just return a stream for the error cases, but that seems honkey. Especially as I don't know how to fail fast like either.

Is there a more idiomatic way to turn a left into an error stream (which in my case prints a usage command then exits the app)?

Answer (score 0):

I think `.valueOr` from cats' `EitherOps` would be a good option, plus factoring into smaller functions.

This would produce something like the following:

```
object Logger {
  def error(msg: String): IO[Unit] = IO(Log.error(msg))
}

def runWithArgs(args: List[String]: Error \/ Stream[IO, ExitCode] =
  for {
    args   <- extractArgs(args)
    x      <- someOtherEither
  } yield Stream.eval(...)

def stream(args: List[String], requestShutdown: IO[Unit]): Stream[IO, ExitCode] =
  runWithArgs(args) valueOr { error =>
    Stream.eval(Logger.error(error.message))
      .map(_ => ExitCode(1))
  }
```

The signature of `.valueOr` is:

```
def valueOr[BB >: B](f: A => BB): BB
```

where you have `A` and `B` as `Either[A, B]`.